# Getting R Shiny DataTables Minimal Example to Work in RMarkdown Doc

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, r-markdown

The DT (datatables) library for R provides the minimal example for working with shiny below at http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html (this works for me)

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

However, the following code in a shiny RMarkdown document doesn't display any output. Why is that?

````
```{r}
library(rmarkdown); library(knitr); library(DT)

mydt = DT::renderDataTable(iris)
DT::dataTableOutput('mydt')
```
````

`renderPrint(DT::dataTableOutput('mydt'))` also doesn't display the table, though it displays some html info about the table.

I don't understand why defining the datatable with DT::renderDataTable() and displaying it with DT::dataTableOutput() works in a shiny app but not a shiny document. Though I presume I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: hello, may I ask if you managed to have the datatable object displayed in a pdf document at the end?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `DT::renderDataTable(iris)`.

````
```{r}
DT::renderDataTable(iris)
```
````

I don't understand what you mean by 1) assigning `DT::renderDataTable(iris)` to an R object `mydt`, 2) printing
`DT::dataTableOutput('mydt')`, and 3) `renderPrint(DT::dataTableOutput('mydt'))`. None of these make sense in this document.

Comment: Hi Yihui, thanks for the response. I understand I can display the table using DT::renderDataTable() as you suggest. But I was hoping to separate the code for defining the DT object from the code displaying it. This is simple to do with ggvis objects in my rmarkdown document, but I hadn't gotten it to work with DT tables, hence this question. Is there a way to define a DT object in one line and then display it in a separate line of code, in an interactive rmarkdown doc?

Comment: @MaxPower I don't quite understand the benefit of using two lines of code, but if you really want, you can certainly do `x = datatable(iris)` then `renderDataTable(x)`. The question is what you are going to do with `x`? In other words, why do you need this DT object?

Comment: Hi Yihui. I have a longish rmarkdown file and wanted to separate code for generating plot objects and displaying them. I don't think datatable(tbl) works when tbl is a reactive function returning a dataset based on user input, which is why I tried to define it with the reactive renderTable function. If its not straightforward to define a reactive DT separate from displaying it, that's fine though too.

Comment: Get the development version of DT from github. Then tbl() which is a reactive table will work